# Stainless steel moka pot with a crema valve for espresso-like crema

Tags: moka, crema

Are there any moka pots (made of stainless steel) that produce crema? I know there is the Bialetti Brikka, but its made of aluminum and that's not what I'm looking for.

I know the Brikka does not produce "real" crema, but it's good enough.

Thanks :)

P.S.: Im not looking for a stainless steel pot (I do own  one), but rather for one that is similar to the Bialetti Brikka i.e. that it has a crema valve.

Comment: [Related](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/78/most-moka-pots-dont-work-on-my-induction-stove-how-can-i-still-use-them), but I'm not sure if the induction-friendly pots (which are generally stainless) produce crema, or a crema-ish substance :)

Comment: Not really an answer, but this question was asked a couple of years ago in a German coffee forum. And back then, nobody knew any stainless steel moka pot with with crema valve: https://www.kaffee-netz.de/threads/espressokanne-edelstahl-crema.85915/

Comment: It seems you can just use the stainless steel bottom with Brikka. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtu9GLXuMf0

Answer (score 5):

My wife and I moved to our new house and we have an induction hob installed there.

We used our brikka(s) a lot and loved the results.

We bought a 4 cup musa for the time being but compared to the brikka it tasted like fermented horse urine.

So I decided to experiment:
Apparently the head from our 2 cup brikka fits the bottom of the 4 cup musa.
It worked! The results are fantastic.
I am going to purchase a 6 cups musa and see if it fits our 4 cup brikka.

The thread on the musa is a bit longer but it doesn't matter: just screw it hard until it locks to put pressure on the seal.

Use just the boiler tank from the musa and all the rest from the brikka as the coffee funnel filter of the musa doesn't have a rubber seal needed for the higher pressure.
Don't put too much water (fill the amount that matches the head. Not the tank)

Good luck!

Comment: @Dav: since the filter used is from the 2 cup brikka I use the same amount of water I would have used for the brikka (2 portions, not 4)

Comment: One wonders how one knows what *fermented horse urine* tastes like?!?!?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to produce crema? Crema tastes quiet terrible if you have ever separated it from an espresso and consumed it.

With that said I don't believe you could ever produce true crema with a Moka pot because you simply can't build enough pressure up to emulsify the insoluble oils in the coffee.

Hope this helps!

Comment: With my bialetti, I get a crema-like substance for a bit which then disappears. Not too sure what's happening

Comment: That's really not helpful. The difference between Moka and Brikka isn't just some crema. Coffee made from Brikka pot tastes much better than from a Moka, using the same coffee.

Comment: Crema in espresso will also disappear, pretty rapidly at that. Crema is basically just air trapped in oil. The air leaks.

Answer (score 1):

The Bialetti [Kitty](http://www.bialetti.com/www.bialetti.com/coffee/stovetop/stainless-pots/kitty-c-1_7_21_37.html), [Musa](http://www.bialetti.com/www.bialetti.com/coffee/stovetop/stainless-pots/musa-c-1_7_21_36.html) and [Venus](http://www.bialetti.com/www.bialetti.com/coffee/stovetop/stainless-pots/venus-c-1_7_21_35.html) are all moka pots and are made of stainless steel, unlike the majority of their range. I own a Bialetti Venus 6-cup and would recommend it highly.

Comment: I'm well aware that there are stainless steel pots on the market as I own one my self. The question is whether there is a stainless steel pot like the Brikka which produces crema using a preassure valve.

Comment: @DamianBast It might be a good idea to update your question (just click the edit link) - that tiny detail might help folks understand the question better.